# Replace x if cond in Mata

Tags: stata

I want to overwrite some elements of a vector `x` with a scalar `a` based on a 0/1 vector `cond`. In pseudocode: `x[cond]=a`.

- `x[cond]` is not the right way of subsetting in Mata. I should use `select(x,cond)`. Unfortunately, this latter object cannot be assigned to.
- `x[selectindex(cond)] = a` fails because such an assignment requires the same dimensions on both sides of the `=`.

I could modify the latter approach to

```
x[selectindex(cond)] = J(sum(cond),1,a)
```

Is that the idiom in Mata? I was expecting something more straightforward because Stata has nice `replace x = a if cond` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, I think that's about as good as you're going to get. `sum(cond)` is safe if `cond` is `0` or `1`, but a more general alternative is:

```
select = selectindex(cond)
x[select] = J(length(select), 1, a)
```

I agree that this is not the simplest syntax. An additional assignment colon operator `:=` would be nice here.

If `x` and `cond` are views, `st_store()` is another option:

```
st_store(., st_viewvars(x), st_viewvars(cond), J(sum(cond), 1, a))
```

If you already know the variable names/indices and don't have to call `st_viewvars()`, all the better.